# how to use conditional if else statement in v-decorator of an ant-design selection

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, antd

I have a Vue app with select option that using ant-design selection

this is my html structure :

```
<a-select
  v-decorator="[
    'race',
    {
      initialValue: profile.race,
      rules: [
       {
         required: true, message: 'Race is required.'
       },
      ]
     },
    ]"
  >
     <a-select-option value=1>Malay</a-select-option>
     <a-select-option value=2>Chinese</a-select-option>
     <a-select-option value=3>Indian</a-select-option>
     <a-select-option value=4>Others</a-select-option>
   </a-select>
```

where the profile.race bring integer value. for showing the race. but in the default view, it's showing just integer instead of the words.

I want in default display it's showing the race word, not the integer value. I also have using `defaultValue`, but it's just the same with `initialValue` how can I play with the conditional statement in `v-decorator`? or anything I can do to solve this problem?

this is the code that i have tried but still did not work.

```
initialValue: '\''+profile.race+'\'',
```

this will bring '1' as value but still it showing '1' instead of the race. but when i'm using

`initialValue: '1'`,
it's work. how can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `initialValue` need to be a string value in order to work as expected

```
initialValue: profile.race + ''
```

This is the working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-sokxn

Comment: Thank you. it's really work perfectly. but i still don't have any idea on how profile.race + ' ' would word? didn't it just return 1 also? but it's worked. thank you @Nguyen You

Comment: the reason is [the Form will test equality with === internally](https://ant.design/components/form/?locale=en-US#this.props.form.getFieldDecorator(id,-options)) and the value of each select option is a string. That's why we need to convert the initialValue into a string.

Comment: i know. but isn't profile.race + ' ' just return 1 as integer?

Comment: nope, `profile.race + ''` will convert the value into a string

Comment: owhh. thank you for the sharing with me. sorry if i'm a little noob

Comment: so if we want to get integer value from this selection the value need to using parsefloat method right to remove the quotes?

Comment: correct ! if you want an integer value, use the `parseInt` method to parse the string value